# iCloud synchronization with Magical Record

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, magicalrecord

I'm working on implementing iCloud backup in my application. I use Magical Record for Core Data stuff.

The question is: how to observe *iCloud synchronization state*, especially **sync start/end**?

The reason: I want to ensure that data is synced on startup and I want to show progress HUD during this process to prevent user from any actions before sync is complete.

There's 2 possible scenario:

1. Some data exists in iCloud (on server). In that case app can observe `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification` and look for `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeInitialImportCompleted` value in `userinfo[type]`.
2. iCloud storage is clean (on server). How to know that iCloud is synced is this case?

I know that iCloud throws `Using local storage: 0/1` during iCloud setup. But cannot find way to be notified exactly on this events.